# Issue with getting a JSON object to work in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to get a JSON object and so to make sure I had it I wrote the code like this:

```
var payload = JSON.parse(
JSON.stringify(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString())
);

console.log(payload);
// { timestamp: '1533564208', device_id: '2nd_test', temperature: '20.0' }
console.log(typeof payload);
// string
```

EDIT - Based on your feedback, I will elaborate further on the code and the type. Below is the full code and what it returns:

```
var payload = Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString();
console.log('payload 0');
console.log(payload);
// { timestamp: "1533564208", device_id: "2nd_test", temperature: "20.0" }
console.log(typeof payload);
//string
var payload2 = JSON.parse(
  Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString()
);
console.log('payload 2');
console.log(payload2);
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse
```

EDIT 2 - To better understand the context I am using the Functions from GCloud with the PubSub trigger. So the data in the buffer is coming from pubsub.

I don't understand why the function JSON.parse crashes though it is obviously a JSON format in a string.

Any clue on this?

Thanks!

Comment: JSON is a serialization of data, not a data type itself. It serializes data as strings.

Comment: You're stringifying a string, leaving you with quotes inside the string you're parsing. So when this is parsed, it doesn't because a JSON object, since their are no key values. It just becomes a string

Comment: You probably just need to parse it without stringifying it.

Comment: I see what you say but one I do directly JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString()) 
 I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @fro that's because it's not valid JSON then.

Comment: yes I understood the issue - I wrote the answer below

Answer (score 1):

The issue was sort of confusing.
Hardcoded in the code the 2 below versions would give me the same result and work fine.

```
payload= { timestamp: "1533564208", device_id: "2nd_test", temperature: "20.0" }
```

and

```
payload='{"timestamp":"1533564208","device_id":"2nd_test","temperature":"20.0"}'
```

But when using the PubSub Gcloud and the Buffer function, I had to make sure to pass in

```
payload='{"timestamp":"1533564208","device_id":"2nd_test","temperature":"20.0"}'
```

and not

```
payload= { timestamp: "1533564208", device_id: "2nd_test", temperature: "20.0" }
```

otherwise it would not consider it as valid JSON.

Comment: I don't know pubsub well enough to say _for sure_, but JSON objects are _strings_ in all languages but Javascript (+NodeJS+Typescript).  Eg, in Python, Kotlin, and many others, only the `payload='{...` code (with the quoted string) would work, to ensure the whole object is a string.  Likely PubSub is simply not using Javascript to de/serialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you "stringified" twice your data, with `.toString()` and with `JSON.stringify`

```js
// since I dont have your data, I will use this as example
var example = { a : 'a', b : 'b' };
var payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(example.toString()));

// will log [object Object]
console.log(payload);
// will log string
console.log(typeof payload);
```

So, when you desserialize using `JSON.parse`, it still remains as string. You only need to serialize once:

```js
var example = { a : 'a', b : 'b' };
var payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(example));

// will log the object correctly
console.log(payload);
// will log object
console.log(typeof payload);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it def helped me! However I still didn't solve my issue. I added some context and edits to better describe the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this ?

```
var payload2 = JSON.parse(
  Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString()
);
```

You could just print the result of `Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString()`

Comment: Well for the simple reason that I need to send a JSON to BigQuery after that and when doing so it throws an error as I need an valid JSON and not a string

Comment: If you convert a string to JSON , it just wraps it in two double quotes. abc => "abc", so try doing it manually

Comment: Not sure I get your comment. I tried JSON.parse on "{"timestamp":"1533564208","device_id":"2nd_test","temperature":"20.0"}" and it didn't work either

Comment: You cant pass that string to `JSON.parse` unless you escape the quotes. so it wont work anyway.  the string should be either `"{\"timestamp\":\"1533564208\",\"device_id\":\"2nd_test\",\"temperature\":\"20.0\"}"` or `'{"timestamp":"1533564208","device_id":"2nd_test","temperature":"20.0"}'`

Comment: Ok yes I see what you mean. However, how can I get this string { timestamp: "1533564208", device_id: "2nd_test", temperature: "20.0" } to be seen as a JSON object?

Comment: JSON is not a different type in JavaScript. its a way we represent data. as i told earlier, if you want just a string as a valid JSON, it should be inside quotes ("<your string>") and the string cannot contain `"`. if you want this string inside an object in JSON, you need `{ "somePropertyName": "<yourstring>"  }` then its a valid JSON object

Comment: Ok I guess I get my issue now: I am using Atom prettier and when saved it would automatically save {"timestamp":"1533564208","device_id":"2nd_test","temperature":"20.0"} as { timestamp: "1533564208", device_id: "2nd_test", temperature: "20.0" } and so this confused me since harde coding in Atom { timestamp: "1533564208", device_id: "2nd_test", temperature: "20.0" } would work.